# using mogrify for lossless conversion from jpg to png

Tags: opencv, imagemagick, png, jpeg, mogrify

I'm trying to losslessly convert a `jpg` image into a `png` image using `mogrify`. To get this result I'm using this command:

```sh
mogrify -format png  test.jpeg
```

However the test to check if the two images are the same fails. To perform the test I use this `python` script:

```py
import cv2

jpg_image = cv2.imread("test.jpeg")
png_image = cv2.imread("test.png")

diff = jpg_image - png_image

cv2.imshow("diff", diff)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.closeAllWindows()
```

If the two images are the same the execution of this script shows a black rectangle.

I tried to make the conversion using `opencv` and it works. This is the `python` script that I used to get the result with `opencv`:

```py
import cv2

jpg_image = cv2.imread("/home/roberto/Downloads/index.jpeg")
cv2.imwrite("/home/roberto/Downloads/index.png", jpg_image)
```

As suggested in the comments below I also ran the `identify -verbose` command on the `png` files generated by `mogrify` and `opencv`. These are the outputs:

`mogrify`

```
Image: index.png24
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 276x183+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 50508
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 153 (0.6)
      mean: 19.2985 (0.0756804)
      standard deviation: 16.1262 (0.06324)
      kurtosis: 4.912
      skewness: 1.86378
      entropy: 0.805148
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 176 (0.690196)
      mean: 64.9359 (0.254651)
      standard deviation: 45.101 (0.176867)
      kurtosis: -0.895497
      skewness: 0.554883
      entropy: 0.968001
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 144.46 (0.566511)
      standard deviation: 50.6283 (0.198542)
      kurtosis: -0.289594
      skewness: -0.566585
      entropy: 0.950031
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 76.2316 (0.298948)
      standard deviation: 40.2384 (0.157798)
      kurtosis: 11.4068
      skewness: 2.70212
      entropy: 0.907726
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.45455
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 276x183+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-03-21T09:51:42+01:00
    date:modify: 2019-03-21T09:51:42+01:00
    png:bKGD: chunk was found (see Background color, above)
    png:cHRM: chunk was found (see Chromaticity, above)
    png:gAMA: gamma=0.45454544 (See Gamma, above)
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
    png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 276, 183
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    png:text: 2 tEXt/zTXt/iTXt chunks were found
    signature: 1bdb735da64a7036eb46f2d257997fbd10044ddc633c2aea5703f1887614709c
  Artifacts:
    filename: index-mogrify.png
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 79.9KB
  Number pixels: 50.5K
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

`opencv`:

```
Image: index-opencv.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 276x183+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: TrueColor
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 50508
    Red:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 153 (0.6)
      mean: 19.299 (0.0756825)
      standard deviation: 16.1246 (0.0632336)
      kurtosis: 4.91164
      skewness: 1.86412
      entropy: 0.80384
    Green:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 175 (0.686275)
      mean: 64.9195 (0.254586)
      standard deviation: 45.064 (0.176722)
      kurtosis: -0.898132
      skewness: 0.553704
      entropy: 0.968909
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 144.561 (0.566908)
      standard deviation: 50.7463 (0.199005)
      kurtosis: -0.296128
      skewness: -0.559014
      entropy: 0.950698
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 76.26 (0.299059)
      standard deviation: 40.2739 (0.157937)
      kurtosis: 11.4583
      skewness: 2.7144
      entropy: 0.907815
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 276x183+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2019-03-21T09:50:20+01:00
    date:modify: 2019-03-21T09:50:20+01:00
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 8
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 8
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 2
    png:IHDR.color_type: 2 (Truecolor)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 276, 183
    png:sRGB: intent=0 (Perceptual Intent)
    signature: 217fe60358faf232f04ccc66dd92ec508fbf82b37858f0b954c87372720b88a1
  Artifacts:
    filename: index-opencv.png
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 89.3KB
  Number pixels: 50.5K
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

can someone explain me which is the difference between the first and the second approach (`mogirfy` vs `opencv`)?

Comment: I suspect your ImageMagick is the Q16 version which will write a 16-bit PNG unless you tell it otherwise whereas OpenCV will write an 8-bit PNG. Try `identify -version` to see your quantisation (`Q` value).

Comment: Also, the ImageMagick codec is not required to work exactly the same as the OpenCV one. It can make different decisions and round differently and still comply with the JPEG specification.

Comment: JPG has a lossy compressions. So any time you read it or write it, it loses some "quality". So you cannot do that with JPG as far as I know, at least not with ImageMagick or its derivatives, since it relies upon libjpeg. Perhaps some other tool might be more effective.

Comment: Rather than just subtracting one image from the other, you could calculate the RMSE, i.e. *Root Mean Squared Error* as an indication of how similar the two images are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation

Comment: @MarkSetchell the version is Q16. I tryied to convert the image using `mogrify  -format png8  ~/Downloads/index.jpeg` but the result is very different from the original `jpg` image.

Comment: @fmw42 it would be impossible to read a `jpg` and write a `jpg` without losing information. But reading a `jpg` and write a `png` (which apply a lossless compression) is actually possible (and this is proofed by the fact that I get the result with `opencv`)

Comment: @MarkSetchell I could compute the RMSE, but I'm not interested in it. I already know that the two images are very very similar, but I want them to be the same bitwise.

Comment: PNG8 will be limited to a palette of 256 colours. I suspect you would want PNG24 to match what OpenCV does, i.e. RGB888

Comment: `@riar`. Yes, you are right once you read the JPG and lose some quality, but write to PNG, then the writing to PNG would be lossless. But I thought you meant you wanted to read the JPG and write to PNG without loss and there would be loss when reading the JPG

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried to use `-format png24` but it produces exactly the same output that i get with `-format png`. I add a bit of information: if a digit the command `file index.jpg` I get this result: `JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 276x183, frames 3`. If I pass to `file` the images produced by `mogrify` and `opencv` I get the same output: `index.png: PNG image data, 276 x 183, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced`.

Comment: Try using `convert test.jpeg png24:test.png`. Also try `identify -verbose OpenCVproducedimage.png` and paste the output under your question by clicking `edit` so we can see what OpenCV is producing.

Comment: I tried the `convert` command and I obtained the same image obtained with `mogrify`. I also ran the command `identify` on both, the `opencv` image and the `convert` image. This are the outputs:
`index-opencv.png PNG 276x183 276x183+0+0 8-bit sRGB 89.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000`
`index-convert.png24 PNG 276x183 276x183+0+0 8-bit sRGB 79.9KB 0.000u 0:00.000`

Comment: You neither used the `-verbose` option I suggested, nor pasted the output into your question like I suggested, so I can't help you much further for the moment. Sorry.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry I didn't read carefully your previous post. I modified the question as you requested. I inserted the output produced by `identify` on the image produced by `mogrify` in order to be consistent with the reset of the question, but you can consider it to be the output of `convert`: they are exactly the same with the exception of the creation timestamp and the following extra-line in the `convert` output: `Pixels per second: 5.051MB`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I thank you for you time and for the new things that I learned from your comments, but I already knew that the two images were almost the same. the problem is that they are not the same and actually we did not sort out how to use `mogrify` to get the same result I get with `opencv`. Therefore I think that the problem presented in the question is not solved (could be that the solution does not exist). Thank you again for your time and for sharing your knowledge with us.

Answer (score 3):

The differences between the two images are negligible. I show the **ImageMagick** produced one on the left and the **OpenCV** produced one on the right.

[image]

[image]

The only differences are a tiny percentage in the pixel data. It is unreasonable to assume that reading a lossy image format such as JPEG with **ImageMagick** will result in an identical image when read by **OpenCV**. The format is inherently lossy and decoders are allowed some discretion in the accuracy they achieve and the tradeoffs they make. **OpenCV** may favour absolute speed and performance, for example. **ImageMagick** may favour compatibility and accuracy.

Don't forget that, although you only see the pixels as integers between 0..255, they actually get transformed into floats, converted into the frequency domain, quantised, packed and compressed and then the reverse happens when reading.